# Get filename of arbitrary function in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

If I have a reference to an arbitrary function, is there a way to get the filename that the function is declared in?

I know how to do this if the function is in the stacktrace, but I can't figure out how to do it if the function has only been declared but never called. The only idea I had was to read all the files, build an AST, and try to find a match, but that seemed overly complicated and error prone (especially for anonymous or dynamically declared functions).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, this information is only available to the debugger, not to the JS code itself.

Comment: That's what I thought :/

Comment: There's no good way to do that. You might be able to create some mess that does it, but it will be error-prone and complicated as you expect. And... why would you like to get that file?

Comment: I'm trying to document where handlers live (or what they're called in express/other frameworks), but often anonymous functions are used, and in large applications it _can_ be helpful to document it all. This isn't critical for all that I'm trying to do, but it was a nice to have :)